# produce list of urls in python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy

*My goal:* to extract all of the transcripts in this [url](http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/), and clean them for my particular use.
I need to recursively extract links which follow a pattern. I am a newbie and am having trouble formulating the full code that will work.

Here are some examples of how the URLs will look:

```
http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/oltl/main/1998transcripts.shtml
http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/oltl/older/2004/oltl-trans-01-20-04.htm
http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/amc/main/2003transcripts.shtml
http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/amc/older/2002/amc-trans-01-08-02.shtml
```

so all begin with `http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts`, then the show abbreviation, then main or older, etc.

*What I've tried so far:*
Getting urls from a particular page is easy with BeautifulSoup but I haven't figured out how to do it recursively. I was thinking of just using a scraper like Scrapy to get all the urls starting from tvmegasite.net/transcripts, and then using the re package to search for ones that match the pattern. I'm still not sure how to make this into a full code.
From what I can guess, these are possibly the kinds of regular expressions that can work:

```
http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts\w+\/main/\d+\w+\.shtml
http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts\w+\/older/\d+/\w+\-\w+\-\d+\-\d+\.shtml
```

Comment: http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/passions/older/2001/pass-trans-09-06-01.shtml `Timmy: It's like Timmy and Tabby are in a giant bath tub and someone pulled out the drain. What's going to happen to Timmy and Tabby?`

Comment: I know, it's hilarious to read these, but I stay away. @maxymoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Scrapy you do not need regular expressions -- or at least you can limit them to a minimum. For example with the `LxmlLinkExtractor` you can set up which URLs to follow (`allow`) and in which XPath-branch (`restrict_xpaths`).

And you can use your regular expressions (which look fine for me at first glance) in in the `allow` restriction -- and for this site you do not need a restriction on XPath.